# ADB Backup does not work for Skype App

Tags: adb, backup, skype

I have a Nexus 5 with Android 6. The ROM is stock and not rooted. My bootloader is locked too.

When I try to save the Skype data files (chats, messages...) nothing will be saved.

```
adb backup -noapk -f Skype.ab com.raider.skype
```

This command will be used to save the data like messages and more.

My question: How can I backup my Skype data?

Comment: It is possible that the app disallows backup. Have you verified this possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to connect  with pc and need to take backup as mentioned in the skype doc

this is not poosbile with android

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA413/how-do-i-back-up-my-configuration-and-instant-message-history?platform=android

this is for windows 
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA413/how-do-i-back-up-my-configuration-and-instant-message-history